# Angular - nvd3 Append line

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js, angularjs-nvd3-directives

I made a Angular-Nvd3 chart and I can't figure out how i can draw a simple line along Y axis as a marker. Example: x:i  y: 180 So, I do not want to treat as a data, that has a value.

Live Edit:

http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/lineChart  (if you now the solution, please share the source code which compatible with this link. )